# Laravel ffmpeg generated MP4 file with audio codec libmp3lame, but no audio on IOS Devices

Tags: laravel

On Laravel `FFMpeg` converting files to `mp4`, but there is no audio on `ios`. Please guide anyone.

I am using the code below:

```
 $ffmpeg_cnv = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();

 $format=new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame', 'libx264');

 $video_cnv = $ffmpeg_cnv->open($uploaded_video_path);

 $video_cnv->save($format,public_path().'/uploads/video/'.$file_name_without_ext.'.mp4');
```

Comment: Hi, do you found how to solve this issue? I have the same problem.